# Responsive Elements display:none; at mobile width then brought back by javascript button but links break on display:block;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Okay so i have the interactive banner. On the right are 2 sliders with featured products.

The design is responsive. Once you reach mobile width. (around 515 px or less) the sliders on the right disapear via (display:none media queries) and are replaced with buttons. You can now click the button to display the appropriate slider.

The problem is its now acting like its parent div is ontop of the slider. or something like that? I am unable to click or use any of the slider content once it is brought back into view via click the button and turning (display:none;) to (display:block;)

Here is my buttons script.

```
 <script>
$('.mobileAdultBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'block');  
    $('.vSlide-markersWrapper').css('margin-left', '-80px');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.productInfo_mobile').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});

$('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#vContentRight').css('display', 'block');  
    $('.vSlide-markersWrapper').css('margin-left', '-43px');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.productInfo_mobile').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});

$('.backBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#vContentRight').css('display', 'none');
    $('#vContentLeft').css('display', 'none');
    $('.vSlide-markersWrapper').css('margin-left', '-19px');
    $('.backBtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobileAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobileYoungAdultBtn').css('display', 'block');
    $('.productInfo_mobile').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
</script>
```

And here is a link to my project: http://portalpacific.net/HAMGO_SmartBanner/

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: If i knew what code was causing the issue I wouldnt need help.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, click the Console tab, and then reload the page. There are Javascript errors.

Comment: Could we reproduce the issue with the code you have provided? If **not** then we need *just enough* code to do so. Links to projects or pages are of no use to future SO users with the same issue.

Comment: I am aware of the simple javascript error failing to load my video's poster image. Although that has nothing to do with my issue of not being able to use my sliders once they are visible in mobile view.

Comment: Paulie if you dont want to help do not help. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

First step: remove `pointer-events: none;` in `@media only screen and (max-width: 515px)
 .vContentContainer`

Second step: Please hide the another vContentContainer(or modify it z-index) if it is not the selected one.

Comment: When i hide the other one using display:none; it still doesnt work. I also removed the pointer event like you suggested. I then tried to move it off screen instead of display:none with a negative left and top margin and no luck. How do i hide it?

Comment: can you please provide the modified example since it work for me http://postimg.org/image/r46czu6al/

Comment: When i select vContentContainer and display none. The slide is display none too because it is a child of the container. Also when i do z-index same thing. If i select the right slider via id and display none. nothing happens. Do you have skype? :)

Comment: I updated the links css and index files. I removed the pointer-events;none. I am still getting the issue.

Comment: there are two div with class "vContentContainer",you should not add "display:none" to the css of "vContentContainer" directly. You should first know which "vContentContainer" should be display, and add "display: none" to that div